# AspCore Client Global Signout with IdentityServer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

in a non core asp mvc application I had a controller action for signout the user globaly

it looked like this

```
   public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
        return Redirect("/");
    }
```

now I have a asp core client and want a logout I tried

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> LogOut()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
            }
            return Redirect("/");
        }
```

**Update**

Now it seems like I get logout, but I'm redirect to a site which requires auth.
I can see that i'm shortly redirected to identity server back again, which automatically sings me again in.

Summarized:
I get logged out in my asp application but not at the identity server.

How can I globally signout ? So that I need to resign in at the identity server?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `OpenIdConnect` authentication, you also need to remote signout. Try to change your code something like below:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> LogOut()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
            await context.Authentication.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                 RedirectUri = "<signed out url>"
            });

            // if you use different scheme name for openid authentication, use below code
            //await context.Authentication.SignOutAsync(<your openid scheme>, new AuthenticationProperties()
            //{
            //   RedirectUri = "/signedout"
            //});
        }
        return Redirect("/");
    }
```

See original sample https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/OpenIdConnectSample/Startup.cs

Answer (score 1):

I've came across the same issue and to solve it I had to clear the Response cookies myself in my IdentityServer application.

```
var cookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Keys;
foreach (var cookie in cookies)
{
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie, new CookieOptions
    {
        Domain = "localhost" // Your host name here
    });
}

// SignOutAsync depends on IdentityServer4 > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync();
```

What I did was, when I client wants to sign-out, I redirect it to my IdentityServer app which clear the Response Cookies as above.

In this code I'm deleting all the Cookies for `localhost`, however you can add a filter there and delete only cookies that IdentityServer makes use of to persist the user authentication.

> Below you'll find more details on this implementation.
>
> http://benjii.me/2016/04/single-sign-out-logout-identity-server-4/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation for ASP.NET Identity Server Single Sign-Out:

[single sign out documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/signout-http.html)

This is a sample tooked from their demo implementation:

```
public ActionResult Signout()
{
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
    return Redirect("/");
}

public void SignoutCleanup(string sid)
{
    var cp = (ClaimsPrincipal)User;
    var sidClaim = cp.FindFirst("sid");
    if (sidClaim != null && sidClaim.Value == sid)
    {
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("Cookies");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say that it is not useful on this context, as we're talking about AspNetCore app and we're making use of OWIN libraries in the managed code. However it works fine in a non asp.net core app which uses OWIN.